# Change tabbar icon color from default blue

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I’m trying to change the tabbar icon color from default blue to red, but I’m getting this error:

> Stray '\342' in program

I’m getting the error at "-(void)recolorItemsWithColor:......." and also at the implementation section. Is there a way to solve this error?

Is there another method to change the tab bar icon from default blue to some other color?

```
@interface UITabBar (ColorExtensions)

– (void)recolorItemsWithColor:(UIColor *)color shadowColor:(UIColor *)shadowColor shadowOffset:(CGSize)shadowOffset shadowBlur:(CGFloat)shadowBlur;

@end
```

Comment: "`Stray '\342' in program`" is not enough for identification, but it is the signature for UTF-8 sequences. The one in the provided source is Unicode code point U+2013 ([EN DASH](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=8192&number=128)), UTF-8 sequence 0xE2 0x80 0x93, 342 200 223 (octal). Thus the triplet "`Stray '\342' in program. Stray '\200' in program. Stray '\223' in program.`" is expected.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Compilation error: stray ‘\302’ in program, etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19198332/compilation-error-stray-302-in-program-etc)

Comment: The "stray" error is a ***very*** common error when copying code from web pages, [PDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Document_Format) documents, through chat (e.g. [Skype Chat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Features_of_Skype#Skype_chat) or [Facebook Messenger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook_Messenger)), etc. The canonical question is *[Compilation error: stray ‘\302’ in program, etc.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19198332)*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a 49x49 png image into your project, then paste these line of code into your app delegate inside the applicationDidFinishLaunching and before adding a subview.

```
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 49);
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
UIImage *tabBarBackgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"49x49.png"];
UIColor *color = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:tabBarBackgroundImage];

[view setBackgroundColor:color];
[color release];
[[tabcontroller tabBar] insertSubview:view atIndex:0];
[view release];
```

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 5):

In the class where you define the tab bar set the property of the
tabBarItem to ->>

```
UITabBarItem *tabBarItem1 = [[self.tabBar.tabBar items] objectAtIndex:0];
[tabBarItem1 setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"campaigns_hover.png"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"campaigns.png"]];
```

It’s a property of tabBarItem and you can change the default blue image to a custom image.
*campaigns_hover.png* is the selected custom image *and*
campaigns.png is the custom image when not selected...

Enjoy the secret... :)

It does not use a private API... The function is defined under the *UITabBarItem.h* class.

Comment: it works. but it doesn't work first time. when i select tab after that it shows the original color of tab icon. any help?

Answer (score 2):

Go to your asset folder, find the asset and click on Identity Inspector. Change "Render As" to Original Image (assuming your icon is the color you want it).

[image]

Comment: How does this answer the question? This seems like a completely bogus answer.

Comment: Not bogus, just ensure your png is the color you want it, and it won't be blue -I prefer non programmatic answers. There is a lot you can do in identity inspector, but also this was 5 years ago.

Answer (score 1):

Are you aware that the code you're trying to use uses private APIs and thus will cause your apps to be rejected?

I don't know about the specific error you're seeing. But if you're looking for another solution, one that'll make it into the App Store, you could try [PESTabBarAdditions](http://snyderp.tumblr.com/post/79975799/pestabbaraddition-is-a-pair-of-classes-i-wrote-to).

Comment: It does not uses a private API.. The function is defined under UITabBarItem.h class.

Comment: I wasn't responding to you, I was responding to the question :P

Comment: Also, my answer is a year older than yours. When I wrote it, there was no public way to do it.

Comment: Oops.. My bad.. Dint saw the date. :)